# Unable to connect to TFS server on clicking View Test Results link in Build Summary

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, nunit

After running nunit tests as part of build process. I would like to see the results of that build. If I want to click on View Test Results link showing in log file opened in VS2010. then it at first throws up error saying unable to connect to server and on clicking again will display the reults in Test Results Window of VS2010. But it is also not displaying any view test results link in TFS web page where any one can see the results. Any idea what is missing.

```
4 projects/solutions compiled
1 test run(s) completed - 0% average pass rate (0% total pass rate)
0/1 test(s) passed, 1 failed, 0 inconclusive, View Test Results
No Code Coverage Results
```

My Changed build configuration file for Nunit:

```
                     <If Condition="[Not DisableTests]" DisplayName="If Not DisableTests" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="1200,1867" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                        <If.Then>
                          <Sequence DisplayName="Run Tests" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="1075,1761" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                              <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                              </scg:Dictionary>
                            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                            <If Condition="[Not TestSpecs Is Nothing]" DisplayName="If Not TestSpecs Is Nothing" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="1053,1637" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                              <If.Then>
                                <ForEach x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestSpec" DisplayName="For Each TestSpec in TestSpecs" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="928,1531" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" Values="[TestSpecs]">
                                  <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestSpec">
                                    <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                      <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestSpec" Name="spec" />
                                    </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                    <TryCatch DisplayName="Try Run Tests" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="898,1425" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                      <TryCatch.Try>
                                        <If Condition="[TypeOf spec Is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestMetadataFileSpec]" DisplayName="If spec Is TestMetadataFileSpec" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="880,1238" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None">
                                          <If.Then>
                                            <Sequence DisplayName="Run MSTest for Metadata File" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,1132">
                                              <Sequence.Variables>
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestMetadataFileSpec" Name="testMetadataFile" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="localTestMetadata" />
                                              </Sequence.Variables>
                                              <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                                  <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                                                </scg:Dictionary>
                                              </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                              <Assign x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestMetadataFileSpec" DisplayName="Assign spec to testMetadataFile" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" To="[testMetadataFile]" Value="[DirectCast(spec, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestMetadataFileSpec)]" />
                                              <mtbwa:ConvertWorkspaceItem DisplayName="Convert Server Path to Local Path" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" Input="[testMetadataFile.MetadataFileName]" Result="[localTestMetadata]" Workspace="[Workspace]" />
                                              <mtbwa:MSTest Category="[testMetadataFile.CategoryFilter]" CommandLineArguments="[testMetadataFile.MSTestCommandLineArgs]" DisplayName="Run MSTest for Metadata File" Flavor="[platformConfiguration.Configuration]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" MaxPriority="[testMetadataFile.MaximumPriority]" MinPriority="[testMetadataFile.MinimumPriority]" PathToResultsFilesRoot="[TestResultsDirectory]" Platform="[platformConfiguration.Platform]" SearchPathRoot="[outputDirectory]" TestLists="[testMetadataFile.TestLists]" TestMetadata="[localTestMetadata]" TestSettings="[String.Empty]" />
                                            </Sequence>
                                          </If.Then>
                                          <If.Else>
                                            <Sequence DisplayName="Run NUnit for Test Assemblies" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="633,1132" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                              <Sequence.Variables>
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestAssemblySpec" Name="testAssembly" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IEnumerable(x:String)" Name="testAssemblies" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="[String.Empty]" Name="testFlavor" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="[String.Empty]" Name="testPlatform" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Name="NUnitResult" />
                                                <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="variable1" />
                                              </Sequence.Variables>
                                              <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                                  <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                                                </scg:Dictionary>
                                              </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                              <Assign x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:TestAssemblySpec" DisplayName="Assign spec to testAssembly" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="611,22" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" To="[testAssembly]" Value="[DirectCast(spec, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestAssemblySpec)]" />
                                              <mtbwa:FindMatchingFiles DisplayName="Find Test Assemblies" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="611,22" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" MatchPattern="[String.Format(&quot;{0}\{1}&quot;, outputDirectory, testAssembly.AssemblyFileSpec)]" Result="[testAssemblies]" />
                                              <If Condition="[testAssemblies.Count() &gt; 0]" DisplayName="If Test Assemblies Found" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="611,884" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                                <If.Then>
                                                  <Sequence DisplayName="Run Tests and Publish Results" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="486,778">
                                                    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                                                        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                                                      </scg:Dictionary>
                                                    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                                                    <mtbwa:InvokeProcess Arguments="[String.Format(&quot;/xml:nunit-tests.xml /framework:net-4.0 {0}&quot;, String.Join(&quot; &quot;,&#xD;&#xA;testAssemblies))]" DisplayName="Invoke NUnit" FileName="[System.IO.Path.Combine(NUnitBinaryDirectory, &quot;nunit-console.exe&quot;)]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,184" Result="[[NUnitResult]]" WorkingDirectory="[outputDirectory]">
                                                      <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
                                                        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                          <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="errOutput" />
                                                          </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                        </ActivityAction>
                                                      </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
                                                      <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
                                                        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                          <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="stdOutput" />
                                                          </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                        </ActivityAction>
                                                      </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
                                                    </mtbwa:InvokeProcess>
                                                    <mtbwa:InvokeProcess Arguments="[String.Format(&quot;-n {0} -t {1} -p &quot;&quot;{2}&quot;&quot; -f {3} -b &quot;&quot;{4}&quot;&quot; -v 2010&quot;,&#xA;              &quot;nunit-tests.xml&quot;,&#xA;              BuildDetail.TeamProject,&#xA;              BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations(0).Platform,&#xA;              BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations(0).Configuration,&#xA;              BuildDetail.BuildNumber)]" DisplayName=" Publish NUnit Results" FileName="[Path.Combine(NUnitTfsPublisherDirectory, &quot;NUnitTfs.exe&quot;)]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,184" WorkingDirectory="[outputDirectory]">
                                                      <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
                                                        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                          <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="errOutput" />
                                                          </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                        </ActivityAction>
                                                      </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.ErrorDataReceived>
                                                      <mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
                                                        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                          <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="stdOutput" />
                                                          </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                                        </ActivityAction>
                                                      </mtbwa:InvokeProcess.OutputDataReceived>
                                                    </mtbwa:InvokeProcess>
                                                    <If Condition="[NUnitResult &lt;&gt; 0]" DisplayName="If NUnit Tests Failed" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,206">
                                                      <If.Then>
                                                        <Assign DisplayName="Set Test Status To Failed" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="291,100">
                                                          <Assign.To>
                                                            <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbc:BuildPhaseStatus">[BuildDetail.TestStatus]</OutArgument>
                                                          </Assign.To>
                                                          <Assign.Value>
                                                            <InArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbc:BuildPhaseStatus">[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Failed]</InArgument>
                                                          </Assign.Value>
                                                        </Assign>
                                                      </If.Then>
                                                    </If>
                                                  </Sequence>
                                                </If.Then>
                                              </If>
                                            </Sequence>
                                          </If.Else>
                                        </If>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewing test results in Web Access was not implemented for Dev10, neither was a protocol handler to open the test results file (trx) in Visual Studio. That explains why the build summary does not show the "View Test Results" link on TFS web page.

Per the Visual Studio issue, does it always throw "unable to connect to server" error the first time you click "View Test Results" in VS? And when you said "clicking again", you mean click "View Test Results" again? Can you check in the event log to see if there is any related error with more information.